# Reading line from CSV file Python given me "" instead of '' (classes)

Tags: python, class, csv, split

I am reading in a CSV file in Python that looks like this:

```
REGION,1910,1920,1930,1940,1950,1960,1970,1980,1990,2000,2010
Alabama,2138093,2348174,2646248,2832961,3061743,3266740,3444165,3893888,4040587,4447100,4779736
Alaska,64356,55036,59278,72524,128643,226167,300382,401851,550043,626932,710231
```

My problem is that when i read the first line it reads it as

```
REGION,1910,1920,1930,1940,1950,1960,1970,1980,1990,2000,2010
```

which in first place doesn't seem as much as a problem. 
But later on I look for a number so a split the string into a list

```
lijst_eerste_regel = self.eerste_regel.split(",")
```

and then look for the index of str(2010) but Python then seems to look for '2010' not "2010". Therefor it won't find the index.

I post the code right here(it is in a class I am having this problem, not sure if that is relevant or not)

```
import io

class Volkstelling:

    def __init__(self,jaartal,csvb):
        """
        >>> vs2010 = Volkstelling(2010, 'vs_bevolkingsaantal.csv')
        """
        import csv
        self.jaartal = jaartal
        self.csvb = csvb

        self.eerste_regel = next(self.csvb)

        if str(jaartal) not in self.eerste_regel:
                raise AssertionError ("geen gegevens beschikbaar")

    def inwoners(self, regio):

        lijst_eerste_regel = self.eerste_regel.split(",")

        plaats_jaartal = lijst_eerste_regel.index(self.jaartal)  # here is where the error occurs

data = """REGION,1910,1920,1930,1940,1950,1960,1970,1980,1990,2000,2010
Alabama,2138093,2348174,2646248,2832961,3061743,3266740,3444165,3893888,4040587,4447100,4779736
Alaska,64356,55036,59278,72524,128643,226167,300382,401851,550043,626932,710231"""
v = Volkstelling('2010',io.StringIO(data))
v.inwoners('Alabama')
## ValueError: '2010' not in list
```

Comment: `lijst_eerste_regel.index(str(self.jaartal))`? You only convert it to a string locally in `__init__`, not in `inwoners`. Or convert the data after you split it, e.g. using a list comprehension `list_eerste_regel = [int(s) for s in self.eerste_regel.split(".")]`.

Comment: lijst_eerste_regel.index(str(self.jaartal)) this is what I tried myself but then it looks for '2010' instead of "2010". The second option I don't quite get. I enter this after lijst_eerste_regel = self.eerste_regel.split(",") or instead of it ?

Comment: `'2010' == "2010"`. Instead of it, it *includes* the split.

Comment: Your Question received a downvote probably because it takes too much time to reproduce the error you described. Note that you can use `io.StringIO` to insert a string instead of a file. Thereby you can integrate your data directly into your example. I proposed an edit to your question which implements this suggestion. (Note that I also had to change the third line of your constructor for this)

Comment: I think I get how it works but I get following error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:" I think it is because the first word is "REGION" which isn't a number

Comment: Yes, sorry, not every value in that line is int-able. The point is that you need to convert so you're comparing like types, it shouldn't really matter which way around.

Comment: @akraf so i put io.StringIO : or (). Is that just on stack overflow or in pycharm the program I use) itself ?

Comment: I just noticed I probably have made a mistake in the second last line of the edit. `v = Volkstelling(??? , io.StringIO(data))` I do not know what goes here.

Comment: `io.StringIO('STRING WITH DATA')` can be used instead of `open('file-with-data.csv','r')`. Its a python object, so it can be used everywhere you use Python. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o)

Comment: @akraf there indeed goes a state like 'Alabama'. (thanks for showing me that method I never used it before)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I changed the code for that to

lijst_eerste_regel = [str(s) for s in self.eerste_regel.split(",")]

when I ask for the index it still gives a value error.

the list looks like this now ["REGION","1910","1920","1930","1940","1950","1960","1970","1980","1990","2000","2010"] 

but I still get ValueError: '2010' is not in list

or can't i just make the int(s) string ? I did this to go around the REGION problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code had several issues leading to 2010 being not found:

1. If you read in files, each line has a [newline character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), commonly represented as `\n`, at the end. Insert the following code into your `inwoners` function to see the newline character behind 2010:

   `print(lijst_eerste_regel)`

   You can remove whitespaces and newlines using the python function `'SOME STRING'.strip()`
2. Your function did not return a value, so you get `None` from `inwoners` even if it would run correctly.

The following example works:

```
import io

class Volkstelling:

    def __init__(self,jaartal,csvb):
        """
        >>> vs2010 = Volkstelling(2010, 'vs_bevolkingsaantal.csv')
        """
        import csv
        self.jaartal = jaartal
        self.csvb = csvb

        self.eerste_regel = next(self.csvb)

        if str(jaartal) not in self.eerste_regel:
                raise AssertionError ("geen gegevens beschikbaar")

    def inwoners(self, regio):

        lijst_eerste_regel = [s.strip() for s in self.eerste_regel.split(",")]
        plaats_jaartal = lijst_eerste_regel.index(self.jaartal) 

        return plaats_jaartal # Returns the column index where to find the no of inhabitants

data = """REGION,1910,1920,1930,1940,1950,1960,1970,1980,1990,2000,2010
Alabama,2138093,2348174,2646248,2832961,3061743,3266740,3444165,3893888,4040587,4447100,4779736
Alaska,64356,55036,59278,72524,128643,226167,300382,401851,550043,626932,710231"""

v2 = Volkstelling('1920',io.StringIO(data))
print(v2.inwoners('Alabama'))
## -> prints 2
v1 = Volkstelling('2010',io.StringIO(data))
print(v1.inwoners('Alabama'))
## -> prints 11
```

Comment: There is no return because my function doesn't end there yet (I know I should have included it anyways) 
sadly the function still doesn't work with me... Just to mention if I look for e.g. for 1920 I have the same problem. As far I know that isn't the end of the line so the problem of "\n" can"t occur there

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "doesn't work". Edit your question to reflect the changes you have made, and describe what output you expect and what you get. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: I will and the error I get is ValueError: 2010 is not in list

Comment: I found the problem 
plaats_jaartal = lijst_eerste_regel.index(self.jaartal)

should be plaats_jaartal = lijst_eerste_regel.index(str(self.jaartal))

now I was wondering since you clearly are longer on stackoverflow then my should I answer this with a correct code or edit my question so it has the correct code in it 

thanks a lot for all the help